# git pre-commit error : Check filenames : .git/hooks/pre-commit; line 25; syntax error : unexpected end of file

Tags: shell, pre-commit-hook

Below is hook code I am using for pre-commit in VS 2019.
I want to restrict some files being committed always. Trying with string.exe. But getting error.
Help needed on this.

```
#!/bin/sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
listchange=$(git diff --name-only) 

echo "Check filenames:"

wrongfilenames=$(
            for filename in $listchange 
            do
                fname= $filename
                if [[ $fname = 'strings.exe' ]]; then 
                    echo $fname;
                    echo "has strings.exe"
                fi
            done
        );
        
if [ -n "$wrongfilenames" ] ; then
echo "The following files need not to commit:"
echo "$wrongfilenames"
echo "Commit rejected, fix it and try again."
exit 1
else
echo "....OK"
```

Comment: You also might want to consider a gitignore file (see https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore). Files and folders listed in gitignore are not added.

Comment: Thank Arjan , it was simplest way. Worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are missing a `fi` at the end of the conditional check.

```
#!/bin/bash
listchange=$(git diff --name-only) 

echo "Check filenames:"

wrongfilenames=$(
    for filename in $listchange 
    do
        if [[ "$filename" = "strings.exe" ]]; then 
            echo "$filename"
            echo "has strings.exe"
            # TODO: take the appropriate action(s) here
            return 1 # => quit with error
        fi
    done
);
        
if [ -n "$wrongfilenames" ] ; then
    echo "The following files need not to commit:"
    echo "$wrongfilenames"
    echo "Commit rejected, fix it and try again."
    exit 1
else
    echo "....OK"
fi
```

NOTE: it is a good practice to add double quotes around $var when checking content against string. Indeed, if the $var has white-spaces it will not work as expected.

Comment: Thanks , resolved that , but now it is committing code having string.exe in changes. What am I missing ? Also for testing I want to have array of file names in 'listchange'. How Can i ?

Comment: It is because there is no action taken (yet) in case the file matches..

Comment: Thanks job, I am new to bash script. Script is running ok on online editor. Need one favor, how can I see my pre-commit bash script's echos in visual studio. I am interested in what listchange=$(git diff --name-only)  returns. rest things are working fine.